# Right side of the Image not fit in mobile browser window

Tags: html, css, grid

I made a few 400x300 pixel image. Each of them contains a letter with a border around them. If I open in mobile browser the the image is bigger than the screen. I tried it in Chrome, Firefox, Opera browser, same results. The problem only exists on mobile phone. No problem on desktop computer even in responsive view.

If I set a lower minimum value, let's say 300px, then the picture fit to the display.
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(400px,1fr));
My phone's display is 720px wide so I don't know why the right side is not visible if I set it to 400px.

I uploaded the html to this [website](https://app-1523272186.000webhostapp.com/x/index.html)

[On my phone this is the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XQxuG.jpg)

My goal is to fit the content to the display on any phone without scrolling.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
  *{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
    body{
      background-color: gray;
    }

    .container{
      display: grid;
      gap: 10px;
      grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(400px,1fr));
      width: 100%;
    }

    .card{
      background-color: lightgray;
    }

    .card img{
      display: block;
      width: 100%;
      /* object-fit: contain; */
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="card">
      <img src="a.png" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="b.png" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="c.png" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="d.png" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card">
      <img src="e.png" alt="">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nothing changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.card img{
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

Using `vw` (viewport width) will fix this problem.
(Or you can also remove the initial-scale=1.0 from your viewport meta tag.)

Comment: Removing initial-scale=1.0 from your viewport meta tag solved the problem. Thanks.